# AppleScript: Error thrown when trying to read UI elements enabled

Tags: macos, applescript, ui-automation, osx-yosemite

If I run the following from Terminal

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get UI elements enabled'
```

I get "true" or "false" as expected

But if I were to create a file with the following contents;

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on supportsAssistiveDevices()
  tell application "System Events"
    set isEnabled to UI elements enabled
    return isEnabled as boolean
  end tell
end supportsAssistiveDevices

log supportsAssistiveDevices()
```

and run it via `./myfile`, I get the following error;

```
./hasguiscript:87:106: execution error: An error of type -10810 has occurred. (-10810)
```

Can anyone help shed some light on why that might be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hasn't worked since before 10.9. You do not enable ui elements as one setting. You must enable each individual application that requests access to ui elements. It's a "security" feature and there's no automated way to enable an application. So your code hasn't worked for over a year now.

```
system preferences->security & privacy->privacy->accessibility
```