# How to set UI Elements Enabled to true in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

```
tell application "System Events"
    if UI elements enabled is true then
        tell application "System Preferences"
            activate
            set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
            display dialog "This script requires access for assistive evices be enabled." & return & return & "To continue, click the OK button and enter an administrative password in the forthcoming security dialog." with icon 1
        end tell
        set UI elements enabled to true

        if UI elements enabled is false then return "user cancelled"
        delay 1
    end if
end tell
```

When I run this, I get an error. "Can’t set UI elements enabled of application to true"

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Extra info: OS X Yosemite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just answered this basic question for someone recently. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680164/applescript-error-thrown-when-trying-to-read-ui-elements-enabled/26687409#26687409).

Answer (score 2):

`UI elements enabled` is a read-only property since OS X Mavericks. Try this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    if not UI elements enabled then
        display dialog "This script requires access for assistive devices be enabled." & return & return & "To continue, click the OK button and enter an administrative password in the forthcoming security dialog." with icon 2
        if button returned of result is equal to "OK" then
            do shell script "sudo sqlite3 'Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db' 'insert or replace into access values (\"kTCCServiceAccessibility\",\"com.apple.ScriptEditor2\",0,1,0,null);'" with administrator privileges
        end if
    end if
end tell
```